# Is possible to install and use Entity Framework in Visual Studio Console/Windows application

Tags: c#, console, entity-framework-6

I am going to create a application in c# .net to handle large data set(in millions). So i want to use Entity Framework here. But i don't know whether I can install and use Entity Framework in Console or Windows application because i don't want to use web applications. I am getting below error when trying to install EF in console application.

> The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possible. But the best way is to have the data handling in a different class library and have the EF reference added to that instead in your console app project.

Comment: while trying to install EF in class library am getting error, posted in my question itself